# Vendor for PO when using a Credit Card

Tags: purchase

When creating a Purchase Order and paying with a credit card, who should the vendor be?

Answer (score 0):

The vendor would be whomever you are buying the service/product from. The credit card is just a method of payment and is irrelevant.  Meaning, if you buy a pizza, you're not paying *Visa* for the pizza, you're paying the *pizza parlor*.